# How to make spinner change text on another screen by using button?

Tags: android, android-widget

On one of my screens I have 3 spinners allowing you to choose your Race, Class, and Alignment. I also have a button that says "Create"(btnCreate). Now when you click create it will bring you to the main play screen. and that screen will says things like,
Name:
Race:
Class:
Title:
etc...

So how would i make the spinner from the previous screen display what was selected and input it on the new screen?

I've tried this:

```
Button btnCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);
    btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            TextView textViewStrRace = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStrRace);
            Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            textViewStrRace.setText(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());

            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PlayScreen.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
    });
```

That just kept force closing the app.

Edit:

Logcat

> 09-14 20:10:15.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-14 20:10:15.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   09-14 20:10:15.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.example.intent_buttontests.CreateNew$1.onClick(CreateNew.java:29)
>   09-14 20:10:15.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
>   09-14 20:10:15.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
>   09-14 20:10:15.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>   09-14 20:10:15.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   09-14 20:10:15.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   09-14 20:10:15.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   09-14 20:10:15.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-14 20:10:15.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   09-14 20:10:15.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   09-14 20:10:15.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   09-14 20:10:15.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mind wanna use the logcat and find where exactly it goes wrong? Lemme know if you do.
Also try getApplicationcontext() instead of v.context.

Comment: I added the LogCat but I still don't know how to fix that issue. and the getApplicationcontext() gave me an error as well

Comment: Add logcat between those statements-

            TextView textViewStrRace = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStrRace);
       Log.i("check","1");
            Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
             Log.i("check","2");
textViewStrRace.setText(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());
          Log.i("check","3");
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PlayScreen.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
           Log.i("check","4");

I use this method whenever  i want to pinpoint a mistake..

Comment: Also y is yr click function inside the clicklistener. If i am not wrong u must be calling this function directly from the xml as
'android:onclick="click"'
So you dont need a clicklistener fot that button.

Comment: When I type in   .setOnClickListener   it creates the OnClick(view v) method.

Comment: How would I put that in the XML then?

Comment: Okay look at this:
This is your xml containing the spinner with a button-

code       -------------------------
       `  <Spinner '
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="click"
            android:text="Button" /> `

Comment: And this will be in your class file:

public void click(View view)
{
TextView textViewStrRace = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStrRace);
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            textViewStrRace.setText(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
  
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Playscreen.class);
     // sending data to new activity
     startActivity(i);
  
 }